# macOS mysql, can not change default password

Tags: mysql, macos

I followed the instructions https://coolestguidesontheplanet.com/get-apache-mysql-php-and-phpmyadmin-working-on-macos-sierra/.
When in safe mode, I open a new terminal window, I type

```
mysql -u root

Welcome to the MySQL monitor. Commands end with; or \ g.
Your MySQL connection id is 7
Server version: July 5, 17 MySQL Community Server (GPL)
```

and a further step

```
mysql> FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> ALTER USER 'root' @ 'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'MyNewPass';
ERROR 1396 (HY000): Operation ALTER USER failed for 'root' @ 'localhost'
```

The password can't be changed. Can you please advise?

Comment: Try running `UPDATE mysql.user SET Password=PASSWORD('new-password') WHERE User='root' AND Host='localhost';` followed by `FLUSH PRIVILEGES;`

Comment: Did you try it?

Comment: Hi, yes error: `mysql> UPDATE mysql.user SET Password=PASSWORD('new-password') WHERE User='root' AND Host='localhost';` ENTER ->
`ERROR 1054 (42S22): Unknown column 'Password' in 'field list'` How to use FLUSH PRIVILEGES ?` mysql> FLUSH PRIVILEGES`

Comment: Hi, apparently the `Password` field was renamed to `authentication_string` in 5.7, so please try: `UPDATE mysql.user SET authentication_string=PASSWORD('MyNewPass') WHERE User='root' AND Host='localhost'; FLUSH PRIVILEGES;`

Comment: I now see that you can try and modify your original query to `ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'MyNewPass';`. Note no white spaces between `'root'` and `@`.

Comment: `mysql> UPDATE mysql.user SET authentication_string=PASSWORD('MyNewPass') WHERE User='root' AND Host='localhost';FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
Query OK, 0 rows affected, 1 warning (0,00 sec)
Rows matched: 0  Changed: 0  Warnings: 1

Query OK, 0 rows affected (0,01 sec)` When I was in safe mode, I can get over Adminer application to the database. Can there something to change it manually?

Comment: Please try following this [tutorial](https://support.rackspace.com/how-to/mysql-resetting-a-lost-mysql-root-password/)

Comment: To the same, no changes to the database. `mysql> UPDATE mysql.user SET authentication_string=PASSWORD('MyNewPass') WHERE User='root' AND Host='localhost';FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
Query OK, 0 rows affected, 1 warning (0,00 sec)
Rows matched: 0  Changed: 0  Warnings: 1`

Answer (score 0):

Tyr this **Alter user 'root'@'localhost' identified by 'new password';**